# move or shift elements in mongo to other json element

Tags: mongodb

I needed to move all `timestamp` elements/field of my collection to `jsonObject` element in `MongoDB`. Is there a query or function to do so.. Below is a sample of document:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5ca307e333ad6127e0ddbe40"),
    "_class" : "com.google.mongo.docs.IvrMongoLog",
    "jsonObject" : {
        "message" : [ 
            {
                "time" : "03:00:23",
                "action" : "call ended succesfully ",
                "user_input" : "user hangup the call",
                "language" : "en"
            }
        ],
        "msisdn" : "89######66"
    },
    "timestamp" : "2019-06-01 12:00:00:00"
}
```

here I want to move `timestamp` element to inside of `jsonObject`. something like this:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5ca307e333ad6127e0ddbe40"),
    "_class" : "com.google.mongo.docs.IvrMongoLog",
    "jsonObject" : {
        "message" : [ 
            {
                "time" : "03:00:23",
                "action" : "call ended succesfully ",
                "user_input" : "user hangup the call",
                "language" : "en"
            }
        ],
        "msisdn" : "89######66",
        "timestamp" : "2019-06-01 12:00:00:00"
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you want to modify existing database structure or just reshape your documents when querying ?

Comment: in all documents I want timstamp to get moved inside jsonObject, once and for all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [$rename](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/rename/)

```
db.col.updateMany({}, { $rename: { 'timestamp': 'jsonObject.timestamp' } }
```

Comment: the query `db.ivrMongoLog.updateMany( {}, { $rename: {'timestamp': 'jsonObject.timestamp' } } )` solved my problem. Thanks a lot @mickl.